# Could this be considered a valid mergesort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort, heap

I tried to do a mergesort function for an assignment without importing `merge` from `heapq`:

```
def mergesort(a):
    if len(a) < 2:
        return a
    return mymerge(mergesort(a[len(a) // 2:]), mergesort(a[:len(a) // 2]))


def mymerge(list1, list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for x in range(len(list2)):
            if list1[0] < list2[x]:
                list2.insert(x, list1[0])
                list1.pop(0)
                break
            if list1[0] > list2[len(list2) - 1]:
                list2.append(list1[0])
                list1.pop(0)
                break
    return list2
```

Could this be considered a valid mergesort or does my function have flaws? Are there ways to improve the `mymerge` function?

Comment: "Could this be considered a valid mergesort" Did you test it? Does it work as such?  Is there a reason you're not using the standard sort functions already provided by Python?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not a merge sort. It never accounts for the fact that `list1` is already sorted. Instead it performs `len(list1)` insertions, every time traversing `list2` from the very beginning.

Each call to `mymerge` is quadratic with respect to the length of the list). At each recursion level \$r\$ there are \$2^r\$ fragments of length \$\dfrac{n}{2^r}\$, so each recursion level will take \$O\left(r\left(\dfrac{n}{2^r}\right)^2\right)\$ time, and summing up for \$r\$ from \$1\$ to \$\log{n}\$ yields the total complexity \$O\left( n^2 \log{n}\right)\$.

The expected runtime of merge sort shall be \$O(n\log{n})\$ (or \$O(n \log^2{n})\$ if done in place).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this looks pretty good. There are just a couple of things that I would change.

1) The `len(list2) - 1` can simply be shortened to `-1` as Python supports negative indexing.

2) I would assign the arguments for `mymerge` to lists

This is the code that I ended up with:

```
def mergesort(a):
    if len(a) < 2:
        return a
    list_1 = mergesort(a[len(a) // 2:])
    list_2 = mergesort(a[:len(a) // 2])
    return mymerge(list_1,list_2)

def mymerge(list1, list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for x in range(len(list2)):
            if list1[0] < list2[x]:
                list2.insert(x, list1[0])
                list1.pop(0)
                break
            if list1[0] > list2[-1]:
                list2.append(list1[0])
                list1.pop(0)
                break
    return list2
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.pop(0)` is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, because all elements must be moved (have a look at the `list` entry [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity))

Instead, you should use `collections.deque`, which has \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ `popleft()` and `pop()` (so both ends are fine, only inserting/deleting in the middle takes long). Otherwise `deque` behaves just like a `list`. You can just convert your `list` to a `deque` when passing it to the sort function or make it a `deque` in the first place.

In addition, `mymerge` is not a very good name. Just call it `merge`. Also, `mergesort` should be `merge_sort` according to Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
from collections import deque


def merge_sort(a):
    if len(a) < 2:
        return a
    list_1 = merge_sort(a[len(a) // 2:])
    list_2 = merge_sort(a[:len(a) // 2])
    return merge(list_1,list_2)


def merge(list1, list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        for x in range(len(list2)):
            if list1[0] < list2[x]:
                list2.insert(x, list1[0])
                list1.popleft()
                break
            if list1[0] > list2[-1]:
                list2.append(list1[0])
                list1.popleft()
                break
    return list2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1,4,1,4,6,8,9,4,2,4,8,9,90,0,5,346,65,47]
    merge_sort(deque(a))
    b = deque([213,25,34,13,,45,6,4,7])
    merge_sort(b)
```

Comment: This is only marginally better: the insertion in the middle of `deque` is still linear, and the entire algorithm remains above quadratic.